# vegetarian vs. meaterarian

Tags: word-usage

1. I am a vegetarian.
2. I am a meaterarian.

---

Is 'meaterarian' the opposite of 'vegetarian'?
Do you have proper expressions for people who like eating meat a lot or who eat meat alone?

Comment: It should be spelled ["**meatarian**"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meatarian), there are too many syllables and the letter "r" in your word *meaterarian*, I doubt it exists in any dictionary! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've not convinced "meatatarian" or any other derivation is a real English word. It certainly is not in the Oxford dictionary. It sounds like a word that has been made up to counter the word "vegetarian", but if such a word existed then it would mean someone who *exclusively* ate meat (ie a *carnivore*), just as "vegetarians" exclusively eat vegetation.

If you mean somebody who eats *anything*, the word you are looking for is "omnivore", although this is really a *classification* that describes all humans as a species - being a vegetarian is a matter of choice. Informally, most people clarify that they are not vegetarian by simply saying they are a "meat eater".

Comment: It's the OP's spelling that is off, the term [**meatarian**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meatarian) is attested by Wiktionary and [**meatatarian**](https://www.askdifference.com/meatatarian-vs-carnivore/) has several references online. .

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, that is why I said "*or any other derivation*". I saw the entry in "wiktionary" but a wiki isn't really an authority on "real" words whereas the Oxford Dictionary is respected as such. I also cover that it is a "made-up" word, and I have no problem with such things... they show the flexibility of the English language that you can make up a new word like "*un-makeuppable*" and natives will know what you *mean* even though it is complete rubbish.

Comment: Before becoming "real", words and expressions are used by its speakers for a much longer time, even decades when an English editor decides to include it in the OED.  Wiktionary is a fine source, it is not without its defects, entries can be vandalised or manipulated but generally speaking, I see this happening less and less.